# Перенести курсор в конец СКОПИРОВАННОГО текста в div.contentEditable

Tags: javascript, nextjs

У меня есть редактируемый пользователем div блок, который отлавливает событие копирования в него текста. Как сделать так, чтобы курсор переместился в конец того текста, который в данный момент вставил пользователь, именно тот который вставил, а не в конец всего текста.